# A quick way to ORDER all IDs randomly in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query, order-by, random

I need to assign random `ID`s to a table. Thus, I create a mapping table as

```
CREATE TABLE t2
(
ID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
SourceID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
UNIQUE INDEX(SourceID),
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1
```

and then added the `ID`s from the main table `t1` as

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO t2 (SourceID) SELECT ID FROM t1 ORDER BY RAND()
```

For example, imagine `t1` is the test results of the students, and we do not want to reveal the student ID (t1.ID) to reviewers (for an anonymous review). Then, we show each record with a new ID stored in `t2`.

```
SELECT t2.ID AS NewID, t1.results FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.ID=t2.SourceID
```

The problem is `t1` is tens of millions of rows and `RAND()` is very very slow.

I do not need a perfect `RAND()` here; just assigning new `ID`s (somehow randomly arranged). Can you think of an approach to do query faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a lot of experimentation by checking the performance. It may help others.

The fastest way (by far) is to do the random rearrangement outside the SQL query.

```
SELECT ID INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/id.csv' 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM t1
```

then

```
shuf -o /tmp/id.csv < /tmp/id.csv
```

and finally the fast `INSERT` step

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/id.csv' INTO TABLE t2 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (SourceID)
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible trick.

Create intermediate table. Copy your `ID` from t1 into it. Add virtual generated column which calculates some hash from `id` value, and index it. Use this table as a source for insertion, add sorting by created index expression, and force it (without index hint it may be ignored due to 100% rows selection.. from the other side, it must be used because it is covering).

An example may be found [there](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e24fd5e8cbb4113200722604c3f92060).

If you think that `BINARY(16)` is too long then you may cut out a part of checksum value and convert it from hexadecimal string to, for example, INT. Of course the index won't be by fact close-to-unique, but this don't mention, as I understand.

PS. It will be, of course, time-expensive on the stage of data copying into the temptable, but the insertion itself must be fast. I cannot predict does total process will be more fast - test it.